# Update string with new string

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to update a table with a new url to replace the old one:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'OLD URL', 'NEWURL') 
WHERE column LIKE '%OLDURL%'
```

This updates it mostly but I only want to replace part of it, and if I put any / in it doesn't work, so if I want to use:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'OLD URL/folder1', 'NEWURL') 
WHERE column LIKE '%OLDURL%'
```

It doesn't work because of the the `/`.

Comment: i would suggest reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially the *"Help others reproduce the problem/ Proof-read before posting!"* parts as the question is missing basic information to give more solid answers/comments... Also See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: So, you want to replace `/folder1` part also to empty string ? eg: `http://google.com/xyz` goes to `https://gog.com` ?

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means.  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix to your second update query is to just include the path component in the replacement:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'OLD URL/folder1', 'NEWURL/folder1') 
WHERE column LIKE '%OLDURL%';
```

Comment: i want to update the folder1 part to say folder 2, but when it put this in and run in phpmyadmin it doesnt find anything

Comment: the column is formated like this ["http:\/\/URL1\/\/1"]

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the replacement pattern in the `where`:

```
UPDATE table1 
    SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'OLD URL/folder1', 'NEWURL') 
    WHERE column LIKE '%OLDURL/folder1%';
```

I'm not sure if that addresses what you mean by "doesn't work", though.

Comment: i think its the way its formated in the database in phpmyadmin its formated like this ["http:\/\/URL1\/\/1"]